# C constants defined at link time

Tags: c, performance, constants

I have a VERY performance-sensitive application, and am curious about if I can save some constants for linking.  I have a number of global constants that I am using (simulation dimensions, for example), which are used an insane amount.  I tried changing them from constants to variables, and the performance dropped dramatically.  Thus, I have created a somewhat convoluted system which assigns constants from a configuration file, and builds an executable explicitly for the requested set of parameters.  Thus, I would like to minimize how much stuff I rebuild for each parameter change.

The question is if I can pre-compile some of my objects, and put the values in at link time.
The most likely implementation I can think of for this would be to include those constants as `const` arguments to the function that needs them, and hope that the compiler/linker optimization results in the same performance as having hardcoded them as `#define` constants.  Any suggestions about how to make this work?

(You know how people say things like "but this doesn't matter unless you're doing this billions of times in scientific computing on a cluster"? -- I'm the guy doing it billions of times in scientific computing on a cluster.  Yes, I also will benchmark anything before fully implementing it.)

Comment: I would like to change the value while recompiling as little as possible.

Comment: What compiler (and version) and processor are you using? Newer versions of gcc can use LTO (Link Time Optimization http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) to optimise compiled code, which may allow you to recompile a file of constants. LTO was introduced 4.5, and replaces IMA in 4.6 onwards, so I assume it is okay. Well worth testing and diffing disassembled (objdump) files to understand impact. I'm very interested in your findings, my Cortex-M4 has few spare cycles!-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming gcc, you could declare the constants with external linkage, put them into their own source file and compile and link with [link-time optimizations](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization#Using_LTO-1).

In case of clang, I recommend a similar approach, but instead of using regular LTO, compile to bitcode using `-emit-llvm -c` and only compile to native code as a last step when linking.

Also, you could leave your code as-is (ie using preprocessor definitions) and trust in [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) to avoid unnecessary recompilation.

Comment: That looks really interesting, and I believe pretty much what I was looking for.  I believe I'm stuck with GCC 4.1.2 (cluster OS is a few year old derivative of an older centos), so I probably can't use it in this case, but it's still really cool.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to analyse why you have the slowdown with variables, probably best by looking into the assembler that is produced, usually this is with option `-S` to the compiler.

There may be a lot of reasons for the speedup if you have constants:

- small integer constants can go to immediates of assembly operations
- The compiler can do loop unrolling
- there can be special arithmetic tricks if the constant is a power of 2

You can get slowdown on the other hand if you only passing pointer to `const` to your function and the compiler can't exclude that your `const` qualified object is aliased. `const` only says that you don't have the right to change the value but the compiler can't know if it changes unexpectedly. Here declaring the pointer with `restrict` might help.

So identify the trouble spots, compare them in assembler with two different versions (constants and `const` qualified variables) and try to find the reason for the slowdown.

Use `inline` to get the trouble spots neatly optimized in place.

If nothing else helps, and if you happen to localize it nicely you might even consider to write a script producing that function with literal constants and compile that little piece of code before every run. If your runs are long, there may well be a pay off for short compilation and relinking.

Comment: @script to export constants, compile, and run: That's currently what I'm doing, just for the entire piece of software--and yes, even with a relatively long compile it's still worth it.  I was just wondering if I could make it less long.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it's not really going to help you. The gains you get from recompiling with different constants are because the compiler knows the values at compile-time and can optimise based on that. If you build an object and link it with constant data later, that's the same as using variables and you'll suffer the performance hit.

Sounds like an interesting problem, there aren't many opportunities for real hairy-chested man's optimisation these days :)

Comment: I believe the aim of GNU gcc LTO is to enable link time optimisatiion, optimising link-ready code as if the compiler had the whole source program: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization I have *NOT* tested and measured this, but IMHO, it would be barely worth their development effort if all LTO gives is something no better than linking variables. But hey, I have been disappointed before ;-)